# Was the instagram story webhook removed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, webhooks

I've been setting up the Instagram business api access and have for the past few days been setting up the webhook for story insights.  When I went to go run a test today the section is no longer in my webhook dropdown.  The only thing that has changed since yesterday is that we added the Marketing Api.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more research it looks like this is a known issue though it isn't included in the depreciation changelogs.  Facebook says they are looking into it https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/553848658320920/.